# Assignment to an array defined outside parloop inside parfor

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

Consider the following code.

```
Wx = zeros(N, N); 
for ii = 1 : 1 : N
        x_ref = X(ii); y_ref = Y(ii);
        nghlst_Local = nghlst(ii, find(nghlst(ii, :))); Nl = length(nghlst_Local);
        x_Local = X(nghlst_Local, 1); y_Local = Y(nghlst_Local, 1);
        PhiU = ones(Nl+1, Nl+1); PhiU(end, end) = 0;
        Phi = ones(Nl+1, Nl+1); Phi(end, end) = 0;
        Bx = zeros(Nl+1,1);
        for jj = 1 : 1 : Nl
            for kk = 1 : 1 : Nl
                rx = x_Local(jj,1) - x_Local(kk,1);
                ry = y_Local(jj,1) - y_Local(kk,1);
                PhiU(jj, kk) = (1 - U(1,1))) / sqrt(rx^2 + ry^2 + c^2);
            end           
            rx = x_ref - x_Local(jj);
            ry = y_ref - y_Local(jj);
            Bx(jj, 1)  = ( (Beta * pi * U(1,1)/(2*r_0*norm(U))) * cos( (pi/2) * (-rx * U(1,1) - ry * U(2,1)) / (r_0 * norm(U)) ) ) / sqrt(rx^2 + ry^2 + c^2) - rx * (1 - Beta * sin( (pi/2) * (-rx * U(1,1) - ry * U(2,1)) / (r_0 * norm(U)) ))/ (rx^2 + ry^2 + c^2)^(3/2);
        end
        invPhiU = inv(PhiU);
        CX  = Bx'  * invPhiU;  CX  = CX (1, 1:end-1); Wx (ii, nghlst_Local) = CX;
end
```

I want to convert the first for loop into parfor loop. The rest of the code works fine, but the following assignment statement does not work when I change for to parfor.

```
Wx (ii, nghlst_Local) = CX;
```

I want to know what is this is wrong and how to remove such errors. Thank you.

Comment: There are some restrictions on slicing a variable in `parfor`. So, the way `nghlst_Local` is used is not going to work. Take a look at [this comment](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/342839-valid-slice-are-restricted-in-parfor-loop#comment_458290) and of course, the entire blog. And, [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variable.html) will give you more info on how to slice your loop.

Comment: @TusharNakini Thank you for your reply.
Instead of converting first for loop, when I try to change second for loop to parfor, Matlab gives the following error "Error: The variable PhiU in a parfor cannot be classified." What does it means?

Comment: Variables that need to be slices should be classified as one of the types mentioned in this [troubleshooting link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/troubleshoot-variables-in-parfor-loops.html). Take a look at the invalid-vs-valid example codes. Sometimes, the statement seems to be logical but `parfor` doesn't allow that syntax.